# Displaying custom Error for static data class in Asp MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello Stackoverflow people,in my mvc project i have static class where i load static data then using it in controllers.

```
  public  class StaticData
{
    public  static List<ITEM_TYPES> _itemTypes ;

    public static void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
           using (pfservicereference.Service1Client ctx = new Service1Client())
            {
                _itemTypes = ctx.GetItemTypes();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new HttpException(500,ex.Message);
        }

    }

}
```

But how to redirect to Custom Error Page If i have HttpException Here?

I Have set customErrors mode="On" But it didnt helps.Is there any way to Redirect?

Comment: You would catch an Exception in your controller, and that is where you would perform the redirect. It is not the job of this static class to perform redirects.

Comment: I'd also use a static constructor instead of the LoadData method see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to custom error page using following approaches,

### Approach 1:

You can use try catch block inside action method and redirect to custom error page.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
             //Code logic here
        }
        catch (HttpException ex)
        {
            if (ex.ErrorCode == 500)
                return RedirectToAction("error", "error");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

### Approach 2:

You can use exception filter for catching errors in application level, based on the error code we can redirect to custom error pages.

For this approach you can create separate exception filter class and mapped application level in global.asax or controller level.

```
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception is HttpException)
        {
            HttpException exception = filterContext.Exception as HttpException;
            if (exception.ErrorCode == 600)
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                { "action", "Error" }, 
                { "controller", "Error" }
            });

            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
```